# How to send email to user who wrote his email address in html by nodemailer in node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a page named email.html in which i am getting email address of user. I want that the mail should be only send to users who entered their email address. Right now, i am sending mail by specifying only one email address.
What should i write in "to: " so that it send mail to only people who enter their emails?
This is the code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'abc@gmail.com',
    pass: '12345'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'abc@gmail.com',
  to: 'cdf@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Testing',
  text: `Only test`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

This is the html file:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="e" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
```

Comment: You can simply submit the form to an endpoint in the backend and send the mail.

Comment: @SureshMangs what to write in "to: " ?

Comment: Read this article           https://www.inelaah.com/node-send-email#:~:text=After%20adding%20the%20code%20for,use(express.